# Separate auth-sources for Tramp and Gnus, or disable auth-sources for Tramp?

Tags: tramp, gnus

I have passwords stored in `.authinfo.gpg` file which I only need for Gnus. I never store passwords for machines or localhost in this `.authinfo.gpg` file (or in any other file).

The problem is when I use Tramp (e.g. `C-x C-f`, then type in `su::`), I constantly get prompted for password for `.authinfo.gpg` which I don't need.

Is it possible to disable password prompt for `.authinfo.gpg` when using Tramp? An alternative solution would be to use some other file for Gnus, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can either use this (I base mine on the command-line arguments):

```
(setq tzz-gnus-running-p (member "gnus" command-line-args))
(setq auth-sources (if tzz-gnus-running-p
                       '("~/.gnus.json.gpg")
                       '("~/.authinfo.json.gpg")))
```

or customize `tramp-completion-use-auth-sources`:

```
tramp-completion-use-auth-sources is a variable defined in ‘tramp.el’.
Its value is t
...
Whether to use ‘auth-source-search’ for completion of user and host names.
```

Comment: Setting `tramp-completion-use-auth-sources` to `nil` does not work for me. I still get prompted for .authinfo.gpg password each time I try to use tramp with `/su::/`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and found the answer in the Emacs [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Password-handling.html) after `(setq tramp-completion-use-auth-sources nil)` didn't work for me. Here is the relevant snippet from the documentation:

> In case you do not want to use an authentication file for TRAMP
> passwords, use connection-local variables like this:
>
> ```
> (connection-local-set-profile-variables  'remote-without-auth-sources '((auth-sources . nil)))
>
>
> (connection-local-set-profiles  '(:application tramp) 'remote-without-auth-sources)
> ```

This has the expected result of TRAMP prompting for a password in the minibuffer (not authinfo.gpg) when trying to open a file as root - in my case, `M-o r` after using `counsel-find-file`.

Note that `password-cache-expiry` applies to TRAMP, so you can tweak this setting to find a good balance between convenience and security regarding the password prompt frequency.